# Issues when adding a JSONOrderedObject into a JSONObject (content surrounded by quotes)

Tags: java, json

I'm having a issue (under a Java development) when adding the a JSONOrderedObject on a JSON parent's document. The code shown below shows how two JSON objects are created in Java (the first one is the format configuration required by a field defined on the second document to be displayed correctly)

```
    final JSONOrderedObject numberFormat2= new JSONOrderedObject();
    numberFormat2.put("@odata.type","#ContentFieldNumberFormat");
    numberFormat2.put("DecimalSeparator","Period");
    numberFormat2.put("UseThousandSeparator", false);        

    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    numberFormat2.write(out);
    System.out.println(out);        


    final JSONOrderedObject reportTemplateJSONObject = new JSONOrderedObject()
    .put("@odata.type","StandardReportTemplate")
    .put("ShowColumnHeaders", true)
    .put("Name", "reportTemplateName")
    .put("Headers", new JSONArray())
    .put("Trailers", new JSONArray())
    .put("ContentFields",
             new JSONArray()
                      .put(new JSONObject().put("FieldName", "RIC").put("Format", JSONObject.NULL))
                      .put(new JSONObject().put("FieldName", "Shares Amount").put("Format", numberFormat2)))
    .put("Condition", new JSONOrderedObject().put("ReportDateRangeType", "Range")
                                                   .put("QueryStartDate", "fromDate")
                                                   .put("QueryEndDate", "endDate")
                                                   .put("ExcludeDeletedEvents", true)
                                                   .put("IncludeCapitalChangeEvents", true)
                                                   .put("IncludeDividendEvents", true)
                                                   .put("IncludeEarningsEvents", true)
                                                   .put("IncludeMergersAndAcquisitionsEvents", true)
                                                   .put("IncludeNominalValueEvents", true)
                                                   .put("IncludePublicEquityOfferingsEvents", true)
                                                   .put("IncludeSharesOutstandingEvents", true)
                                                   .put("IncludeVotingRightsEvents", true)
                                                   .put("CorporateActionsCapitalChangeType", "CapitalChangeExDate")
                                                   .put("CorporateActionsDividendsType", "DividendPayDate")
                                                   .put("CorporateActionsEarningsType", "PeriodEndDate"));

    StringWriter out3 = new StringWriter();
    reportTemplateJSONObject.write(out3);
    System.out.println(out3);
```

I've also added some stuff to display the contents of each objects

For the child document, everything is displayed ok, as you can see below:

```
  "@odata.type":"#ContentFieldNumberFormat","DecimalSeparator":"Period","UseThousandSeparator":false}
```

But when it's inserted into the parent document, the contents are being sorrounded by quotes (and any of them inside it escaped by backslashes)

```
{"@odata.type":"StandardReportTemplate","ShowColumnHeaders":true,"Name":"reportTemplateName","Headers":[],"Trailers":[],"ContentFields":[{"Format":null,"FieldName":"RIC"},{"Format":"{\"@odata.type\":\"#ContentFieldNumberFormat\",\"DecimalSeparator\":\"Period\",\"UseThousandSeparator\":false}","FieldName":"Shares Amount"}],"Condition":{"ReportDateRangeType":"Range","QueryStartDate":"fromDate","QueryEndDate":"endDate","ExcludeDeletedEvents":true,"IncludeCapitalChangeEvents":true,"IncludeDividendEvents":true,"IncludeEarningsEvents":true,"IncludeMergersAndAcquisitionsEvents":true,"IncludeNominalValueEvents":true,"IncludePublicEquityOfferingsEvents":true,"IncludeSharesOutstandingEvents":true,"IncludeVotingRightsEvents":true,"CorporateActionsCapitalChangeType":"CapitalChangeExDate","CorporateActionsDividendsType":"DividendPayDate","CorporateActionsEarningsType":"PeriodEndDate"}}
```

(Pay attention of the excerpt of the above shown next)

```
{"Format":"{\"@odata.type\":\"#ContentFieldNumberFormat\",\"DecimalSeparator\":\"Period\",\"UseThousandSeparator\":false}"
```

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not "surrounded by quotes". You've toString()'d that object. The content just happens to be a JSON object.

Comment: Thank you, @cricket_007 for your comment. Changing the class we use for creating the `numberFormat2`object (moving from a `JSONOrderedObject` class instance to a `JSONObject` one) everything works fine. But the problem here is that we must guarantee the order of the attributes defined there (so the "ordered" version is required)

Comment: JSON, like a Hashmap, doesn't need to be ordered

Comment: In the API we are using, that's a requirement, @cricket_007. If you use, as an example, a non-ordered container (like `JSONObject`) when formatting the output data, you will always get a `Bad Request` message. So that's the reason for using the ordered approach, that works fine every time.

Comment: Well, then you must implement `JSONOrderedObject#put(String key, JSONOrderedObject value)` yourself so it is not the default behavior that will put in `String.valueOf(value)`

Comment: In any case, the API really should not care about order unless it actually iterates over the keys. Accessing `json["key"]` doesn't respect ordering

Comment: Thank you for your last comments @cricket_007. Regarding the first one, that's what I did. For the second one, I entirely agree with you. but the API we are accessing offers such behaviuor, One more time, thank you